# Android AOSP - adding app to /packages/apps

Tags: android, android-source

I need to add a new app that I wrote in Eclipse to the `/packages/apps` folder in Android AOSP. But after the copying the app folder into that directory, building, and rebooting Android, I don't see my app in the launcher.

I see that the `Android.mk` file is missing. I want to ask what is the simplest `Android.mk` that could be written for a Eclipse project to make it compile. I tried the following (I put the file in the app's directory)

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApp

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

I don't see any compilation errors, but still I don't see it in the launcher.

Can anyone tell what is missing in my `Android.mk` file? (I took the code from the Soundrecorder app)

Is there any other file that needs to be edited to include an app into `/packages/apps` folder ?

Answer (score 6):

The steps are as follows:

1. Place `MyApp` folder under `/packages/apps`.
2. Add `Android.mk` to `/packages/apps/MyApp` (*yours should work*).
3. Add `MyApp` entry to `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` in the target product `.mk` file under [`/build/target/product`](https://github.com/android/platform_build/tree/master/target/product) (*missed the step*). E.g. when building for `sdk`, the entry in `sdk.mk` is

   ```
   PRODUCT_PACKAGES := \
           ... \
           SomeApp \
           MyApp
   ```

Comment: any reference documentation for this? (incase it's changed)

Comment: @Blundell, if I remember correctly I saw the idea in [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Embedded-Android-Porting-Extending-Customizing/dp/1449308295) + experimented on my own (but I can be mistaken).