# Using compiled SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-source

I am trying to compile android-6.0.1 from source and use the compiled SDK in Android Studio. To compile the SDK, I tried the commands:

```
 $ lunch sdk-eng
 $ make sdk
```

Also tried:

```
 $ lunch sdk-eng
 $ make PRODUCT-sdk-sdk showcommands
```

Compilation results 0 errors.

To add the SDK in Android Studio, I checked SO questions on how to change SDK path. I am facing issues after path change. The folder of my compiled SDK has key folders named `android-6.0.1` such as

```
 platforms/android-6.0.1
 build-tools/android-6.0.1
```

Complete set of folders inside SDK is:

```
 add-ons  build-tools  docs  documentation.html  extras  platforms  platform-tools  RELEASE_NOTES.html  samples  system-images  tests
```

The compiled SDK is for API version 23.

The following are steps I tried so far to add the compiled SDK in Android Studio (version 2.1.2)

1) change sdk path -> Gradle sync begins ->

[image]

(Remember the sdk folder does have a build tools folder)

My apps `build.gradle` contains

```
android {
 compileSdkVersion 23
 buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sdktest"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

2) `build.gradle` does not allow strings like `6.0.1` for platform name, so I  attempted to rename relevant folders

- platforms/android-6.0.1 --> platforms/android-23
- build-tools/android-6.0.1 --> build-tools/23.0.0
- system-images/android-6.0.1 --> system-images/android-23

Modified `build-tools/23.0.0/source.properties` to contain `Pkg.Revision=23.0.0`

I compared the `build-tools` folder in meld (left is the new compiled SDK; the folder hierarchy is identical, although I haven't checked all the differences yet):

[image]

**[Update]**

I tried to follow the Android Studio prompts to install build tools version 23.0.0 and also `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1` -> gradle sync starts again, and prints the following in the log (and then remains stuck):

```
  build-tools/23.0.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried installing the package `lib32z1` but it didn't resolve the problem. Has anyone tried fixing it on Debian jessie (64 bit) ?

Comment: _"so I attempted to rename relevant folders"_ No need to do that. General steps are: 1) change SDK path in AS by going to `Project Structure -> SDK Location` and pointing to the compiled SDK `out/host/linux-x86/sdk/android-sdk_eng.xxx_linux-x86`; 2) follow the IDE prompt and install the Build Tools as you mentioned in step 1.

Comment: You seem to be in the right condition to check [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857285/android-aosp-adding-app-to-packages-apps/40494023#40494023) to quite an old question of yours. Remember, by accepting a useful answer you indicate to the future issue seekers that the answer was correct, so helping them to resolve the issue faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the following libraries to solve it:

- libc6-i386
- lib32stdc++6
- lib32gcc1
- lib32ncurses5

I found the solution at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22592888