# Custom sdk with android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-source, dalvik

I have built the sdk from AOSP source tree and directed the sdk path in the Android Studio to the new sdk directory. I have checked android.jar and verified that it contains my added classes, fields, and changes.

But when I try to code in the studio I do not find the added fields in code suggestions. For example I added a filed ActivityName in AccessibilityServiceInfo class. But I do not see that. It still contains the original fields. But if I analyze the android.jar file from platform directory under sdk, i can see it is already there.

What I did wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822299/using-compiled-sdk-in-android-studio#comment68864286_40822299

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `build.gradle` `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` of your app's project both configured to the correct folder under `Android\sdk\platforms\android-XX`
(XX == The platform you generated your SDK from)