# How can I add a new app as a new functionality into AOSP Settings?

Tags: android, package, android-source

I know the structure of AOSP well, and I am familiar with AOSP Settings. However, I have no experience in customizing the Settings codes, and adding a new functionality into it. I have a straightforward question: How can I add a new developed Android application into Android Settings.

Extra note: I do not want to place a new  application in `packages/apps` directory. I exactly want to add a complete app to the `packages/apps/settings` directory, and embed it into the settings menu. I know how to custom the menu, but adding a complete application to the setting project is very challenging.

Any solution or clue is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add an application in AOSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137706/how-do-i-add-an-application-in-aosp)

Comment: @Amirhosein Not exactly! Thank you for your help, but I need more technical guidance to embed my app into the setting app, not into `packages/apps` directory. I added a few extra notes to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I added my Updater package in `packages/apps` with necessary changes into the make files of AOSP root (e.g., AOSP_x86_64.mk) and Android.bp file of the local package. I have added it to `system_ext` partition by activating the `system_ext_specific: true` option within the bp file. Also, we can do the same thing with product partition by activating the `product_specific: true` option. Then, we need to only link it to the Settings menu in the right place.